# Form Value is getting repopulated when tried to be cleared/reset in Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, forms, form-control, formgroups

I have a question while working with angular forms. There are two tabs that use the same component. One FormGroup is present in this component which has few dropdowns to be populated. The task is to hit clearAll button that will clear these dropdowns values/form values. This clearAll button works fine if we load the two tabs from stratch and work on them individually.

The clearAll button uses

```
pubic clearAll()
    {
      this.defaultFieldValueList.forEach( (d) = {
        this.searchForm.get(d.name).setValue("",{emitEvent: 
            false, onlySelf: true})
         })
        console.log(this.searchForm.get("CCY") // shows exact set as ""
        console.log(this.searchForm) //shows still CCY  value and other dropdown values that were populated

    }
```

and we see the form is cleared.

But the issue is when we successfully clear the form on one tab component and **toggle** to the other tab, and try to populate the form and clear it, the values get cleared and popup again. This means that form is not getting set with null correctly in clearAll function. Rather, it gets the populated value always.

Is there any way to force reset the form? Even after this.formGroupName.reset() for entire form it resets other fields but still some dropdowns get the populated value.

Also, there is valueChanges defined for this form, so the valueOnChanges get triggered once we try to reset this form. We want to ignore call to this valueChanges when we change the value of the form. Tried the following, but it still calls valueChanges.

The valueChanges code in init is as follows:

```
this.searchForm.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(300), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(x=> {

   this.DBlist.forEach(key=> {
      if(x[key.name]!='')
       {
       //append key.name and x[key.name] to url parameters
       }
    })
})
```

Is there a way, we can ensure that the form will always have the value of most recent update operation and the values are not repopulated to formControl. Even though formControl shows value as "" in console, but the form when printed shows the old values. Also, can we avoid that valueChanges does not get called when the form values is set via setValue.

Comment: please post a reproducible example not just code fragments. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @E.Maggini Please can you review the code, clearAll works fine when we are on individual tab that use same underlying component. But when we toggle from one tab to other and try to clear the form, the values get repopulated and the form just shows old value. Can this form be forced to udpate with "" values. Also, after the clearAll if this setValue does not call ValueChanges it will be great.